# When Homura took over the world it was playing "I was Waiting For This Moment" but is it actually someone else's song in reverse?

Tags: madoka-magica, theme-song

So I went ahead and tried exploring and reversing YouTube videos that i made into mp3 files which one of them being the "I Was Waiting For This Moment" song from when Homura you know, took over the universe. And I played it backwards using https://audioalter.com/reverse/

So um it sounded exactly like another song from Madoka Magica... I remember the music but not the name... If your watching it now just wait a few seconds and you'll see. So am i going crazy or what...

Can someone else listen to the original song, and the reversed theme and tell me if I'm right?
And if they're able to the name of the other song?
(It sounds like it at the beginning-middle the end; i just don't know)
BTW: The two links takes you to a google drive file so your safe :D

[Reversed](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1k1VEvOi-Ah0uCaUeQcAjSp6lXBsiQtzp/view?usp=sharing)

[Original](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1n_H8SMSqKH3nV7tTzl6M7_rkbn9p_dIz/view?usp=sharing)